# edit iframe name with imacro js

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a code that simply edits the name of the frame, in normal page its working:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true
or any single page with recaptcha.

but on this site have 3 frames with recaptcha:
http://multytabrailblocks.tk/

the code does not change the name of the frame, Because it's frame inside frame. 
I need help to fix it please

```
FRAME F=2
URL GOTO=javascript:((function(){var%20a=window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');var%20k='';for(var%20x=0;x<a.length;x++)if(a[x].src.includes('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe')){a[x].setAttribute("name","newname")}}))()
FRAME NAME="newname"
'frame name still not "newname"
```

Comment: I'm unsure that it's possible to solve this problem by means of `URL GOTO=javascript:{}` from an iim-macro.. However, I managed to change the frame name inside of another frame by applying the [Javascript Scripting Interface for Firefox](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface).

Comment: @Shugar This option checked on my settings, can you share please the code with which you succeeded?

Comment: Well, I didn't mean any _options on your settings_, just talked about js-scripts instead  of iim-macros.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is following:

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=https://www.yahoo.com/");
// there's no "newname" yet
alert(iimPlayCode("FRAME name=newname"));

for (i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
    try {
        window.frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("name","newname");
    } catch(e) {
    }
}

// now it should be alright
iimPlayCode("FRAME name=newname" + "\n" + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=HTM");
alert(iimGetExtract());
```

Try it under 'iMacros for Firefox' v.8.9.7 and adjust this script for your issue.

I assume that you know the basics of JavaScript.